Elegant way to query this data
I have this weird requirement to generate an output where period can have values 1 to 36. So the output needs to have 36 + 3 columns. Is there any better way to do this. Please help. Thanks in advance
Updated 1st Nov 2024
Sample data is as below:



bdate
id
period
ct
value




2024-06-28
1
1
ct1
1.4563


2024-06-28
1
1
ct2
2.0023


2024-06-28
1
1
ct3
3.4563


2024-06-28
1
1
ct4
4.0023


2024-06-28
1
2
ct1
1.4563


2024-06-28
1
2
ct2
2.0023


2024-06-28
1
2
ct3
3.4563


2024-06-28
1
2
ct4
4.0023


2024-06-28
1
3
ct1
0.4563


2024-06-28
1
3
ct2
1.0023


2024-06-28
1
3
ct3
2.4563


2024-06-28
1
3
ct4
3.0023



Expected output is



bdate
id
period_1
period_2
period_3
period_36




2024-06-28
1
10.9172
10.9172
6.9172
0



Here the list of columns will be from period_1 to period_36.
CREATE or replace TABLE test_8192590.some_table
(
    `bdate` Date,
    `id` UInt32,
    `period` UInt32,
    `ct` String,
    `value` Float64
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
ORDER BY (bdate, id)
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192;

insert into test_8192590.some_table VALUES 
('2024-06-28',1,1,'ct1',1.4563),
('2024-06-28',1,1,'ct2',2.0023),
('2024-06-28',1,1,'ct3',3.4563),
('2024-06-28',1,1,'ct4',4.0023),
('2024-06-28',1,2,'ct1',1.4563),
('2024-06-28',1,2,'ct2',2.0023),
('2024-06-28',1,2,'ct3',3.4563),
('2024-06-28',1,2,'ct4',4.0023),
('2024-06-28',1,3,'ct1',0.4563),
('2024-06-28',1,3,'ct2',1.0023),
('2024-06-28',1,3,'ct3',2.4563),
('2024-06-28',1,3,'ct4',3.0023);

Select date
  , id
  , period
  , case when period = 1 then sum(value) else 0 end as period_1,
  , case when period = 1 then sum(value) else 0 end as period_2,
…
  , case when period = 36 then sum(value) else 0 end as period_36
from some_table
group by bdate, id, period


Please provide both sample input data and the expected result as tables with text and tag the RDBMS you use.

Have you considered GENERATE_SERIES and Pivot?

Also, don't you mean sum(case when period = 1 then value else 0 end) as period_1, ?

Which dbms are you using?

@BartMcEndree, how do you know which dbms OP is using?

I looked at user2459396's question history. They mostly ask about Postgres.

What is 'not elegant' about simply listing 36 column expressions? There are more elaborate ways of doing it, like dynamic SQL; or tally tables with pivoting etc, but this is very easy to build, easy to understand, easy to maintain.

Found the answer, it is easy like this
WITH CAST(sumMap([period], [value]), 'Map(UInt32, Float64)') AS map
select bdate
  , id
  , period
  , map[1] AS period_1
  , map[2] AS period_2
  , map[3] AS period_3
from test_8192590.some_table
group by bdate, id, period
order by bdate, id, period;

